# Parsing data from one row into multiple rows in CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, ssis, rows

I am new to SSIS and need some help figuring out how to parse this data. The Course-level Learning Objectives need to be split into multiple rows and the data in the [] needs to be moved to it's own column. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The CSV file contains multiple records. The example below is just one record.

**Current format of CSV file**:

```
Prefix/Code,Name,Credits,Description,Course-level Learning Objectives

ABE 095,Keys to Academic Success,3.0 ,"Basic .. assessment. ","   

Identify learn. [EXPLORE] 
Evaluate personal,  goals. [ACT] 
Utilize development. [EXPLORE] 
"
```

**Format the file needs to be in**

```
Prefix/Code,Name,Credits,Description,Course-level Learning Objectives,Type

ABE 095,Keys to Academic Success,3.0 ,"Basic .. assessment.","Identify learn.", [EXPLORE] 
ABE 095,Keys to Academic Success,3.0 ,"Basic .. assessment.","Evaluate goals.", [ACT] 
ABE 095,Keys to Academic Success,3.0 ,"Basic .. assessment.","Utilize dev.", [EXPLORE]
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting my post. I have been doing hours of research to figure out how to do this and it's driving me nuts. billinkc: I've noticed many of the posts I've come across have been answered by you. Could you help me with a solution?

Comment: Will you be able to store data at least temporarily in a database table? For example SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server is available to insert the data into tables.

Comment: Do you have the rights to create a user defined scalar-valued function in your SQL Server database? Also, what version of SQL Server is it? 2008?

Comment: My answer below assumes that yes you can create a user defined scalar-valued function and you are using SQL Server 2008. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic steps:

1. Get the data into a table in SQL Server using SSIS
2. Slay the "Course-level Learning Objectives" dragon
3. Unpivot the results

Here is a code snippet for the "Nth" index function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_NthIndex] 
                   (@Input     VARCHAR(8000), 
                    @Delimiter CHAR(1), 
                    @Ordinal   INT) 

    RETURNS INT 
    AS 

      BEGIN 

        DECLARE  @Pointer INT, 
                 @Last    INT, 
                 @Count   INT 

        SET @Pointer = 1 
        SET @Last = 0 
        SET @Count = 1 

        WHILE (2 > 1) 
          BEGIN 
            SET @Pointer = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Input,@Pointer) 
            IF @Pointer = 0 
              BREAK 
            IF @Count = @Ordinal 

              BEGIN 
                SET @Last = @Pointer 
                BREAK 
              END 
            SET @Count = @Count + 1 
            SET @Pointer = @Pointer + 1 

          END 

        RETURN @Last 

      END

    GO
;
```

This method solves it using [Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the "Nth" index function, and [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
WITH s1
    AS ( SELECT 'ABE 095' AS [Prefix/Code]
              , 'Keys to Academic Success' AS Name
              , '3.0' AS Credits
              , 'Basic .. assessment. ' AS Description
              , '   

Identify learn. [EXPLORE] 
Evaluate personal,  goals. [ACT] 
Utilize development. [EXPLORE] 
' AS [Course-level Learning Objectives]
       ) , s2
    AS ( SELECT [Prefix/Code]
              , Name
              , Credits
              , Description
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 2
                                ) + 2 AS Type1Start
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 3
                                ) - dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                                               ) , 2
                                                    ) + 0 AS Type1Length
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 3
                                ) + 2 AS Type2Start
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 4
                                ) - dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                                               ) , 3
                                                    ) + 0 AS Type2Length
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 4
                                ) + 2 AS Type3Start
              , dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                           ) , 5
                                ) - dbo.udf_NthIndex( [Course-level Learning Objectives] , CHAR( 13
                                                                                               ) , 4
                                                    ) + 0 AS Type3Length
           FROM s1
       ) , s3
    AS ( SELECT s2.[Prefix/Code]
              , s2.Name
              , s2.Credits
              , s2.Description
              , RTRIM( LTRIM( SUBSTRING( s1.[Course-level Learning Objectives] , s2.Type1Start , Type1Length
                                       )
                            )
                     )AS Type1_chunk
              , RTRIM( LTRIM( SUBSTRING( s1.[Course-level Learning Objectives] , s2.Type2Start , Type2Length
                                       )
                            )
                     )AS Type2_chunk
              , RTRIM( LTRIM( SUBSTRING( s1.[Course-level Learning Objectives] , s2.Type3Start , Type3Length
                                       )
                            )
                     )AS Type3_chunk
           FROM s1 , s2
       ) , unpivot1
    AS ( SELECT [Prefix/Code]
              , Name
              , Credits
              , Description
              , Type_chunk
           FROM( 
                 SELECT [Prefix/Code]
                      , Name
                      , Credits
                      , Description
                      , Type1_chunk
                      , Type2_chunk
                      , Type3_chunk
                   FROM s3
               )p UNPIVOT( Type_chunk FOR Type_descrip IN( Type1_chunk
                                                         , Type2_chunk
                                                         , Type3_chunk
                                                         )
                                                         )AS unpvt
       )
    SELECT [Prefix/Code]
         , Name
         , Credits
         , Description
         --, Type_chunk
         , LEFT( u.Type_chunk , -2 + dbo.udf_NthIndex( u.Type_chunk , '[' , 1
                                                     )
               )AS [Learning Objectives]
         , RIGHT( u.Type_chunk , 1 + LEN( u.Type_chunk
                                        ) - dbo.udf_NthIndex( u.Type_chunk , '[' , 1
                                                            )
                )AS Type
      FROM unpivot1 u;
```

If you are able to use Regular Expressions, you can save a bit of code. Using RegEx in SQL Server 2008 requires CLR. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626022) does a great job of showing you how to do that step by step. The solution works good enough for a smallish number of "Type" values per course.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to consume the file in SSIS 2008 but can be done in SSIS 2012 and then pivot the data,if you want to do it in SSIS 2008 You should use a script task to format the file and then use flat file source in DF, in script task you should use a filereader to achive it ,for more info on spliting this file see this link http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/12/parsing-data-from-one-row-into-multiple.html

Comment: Does SSIS 2012 off more tools for data parsing? I am familiar with vb and java, so I understand c#, but the pain in butt is 2008 doesn't offer debugging for scripts, which makes if very difficult to find where my errors are.

Comment: if it is script component you cannot debug in ssis 2008 but you can debug in script task, to do so you have to set the propery of solution to 32 bit, alternatively you can always add MsgBox(column.ToString()) to see the results during execution